# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{{{a^3} + {b^3}}}{{{a^2} + ab + {b^2}}} \ge 2\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}$ for $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c \geq 0,a^3+b^3+c^3=3$. Prove that
> $$\frac{{{a^3} + {b^3}}}{{{a^2} + ab + {b^2}}} + \frac{{{b^3} + {c^3}}}{{{b^2} + bc + {c^2}}} + \frac{{{c^3} + {a^3}}}{{{c^2} + ca + {a^2}}} \ge 2\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}.$$

The problem I can prove the left-hand side not less than.
$$2\frac{{\left( {a + b + c} \right)}}{3};2\sqrt {\frac{{{a^2} + {b^2} + {c^2}}}{3}}.$$
I tried with $2\sqrt[3]{{\frac{{{a^3} + {b^3} + {c^3}}}{3}}}$ but it was very difficult, and I couldn't solve it. The problem at hand is even more challenging.
The source of the problem is here:
(arqady)
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1197896p5875491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of a proof**.

We have
$$\frac{a^3 + b^3}{a^2 + ab + b^2}
- \frac{a + b}{3} = \frac{2(a + b)(a - b)^2}{3(a^2 + ab + b^2)}
\ge \frac59(a - b)^2 \tag{1}$$
where we use $18(a + b) \ge 15(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ (see Remark 1 at the end).

Using $\sqrt[4]{x} \le \frac{x + 3}{4}$ for all $x \ge 0$ (by AM-GM), we have
$$2\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}
= \frac{2}{3^{1/3}}\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\cdot 3^{4/3}}
\le \frac{2}{3^{1/3}}\cdot \frac{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\cdot 3^{4/3} + 3}{4}. \tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac{a+b}{3} + \frac59(a - b)^2\right) \ge \frac{2}{3^{1/3}}\cdot \frac{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\cdot 3^{4/3} + 3}{4}$$
or
$$\frac{2(a + b + c)}{3} + \frac{10}{9}(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca)
- \frac{a^4 + b^4 + c^4}{2} - \frac12 \sqrt[3]{9} \ge 0.\tag{3}$$

(3) is true. We may use the pqr method.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Remark 1*: Let $p = a + b$ and $q = ab$.
Then $p \le 2^{2/3}$ by using $\frac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3 + b^3}{2}}$ (the power mean inequality).
We need to prove that $18p \ge 15p^2 - 15q$. If $p \le 1$, clearly it is true.
If $1 < p \le 2^{2/3}$,
from $a^3+b^3 \le 1$, we have $p(p^2 - 3q) \le 1$ which results in
$3q \ge p^2 - \frac{1}{p}$.
Thus, we have
$18p - 15p^2 + 15q 
\ge 18p - 15p^2 + 5\cdot (p^2 - 1/p)
= -10p^2 + 18p - \frac{5}{p} \ge 0.$
We are done.